# Is it possible to use ajax to load a single php function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Example:
I have written a php script like below:

```
<?PHP 
    function _hello(){  "Hello world!"; }
    function _bye(){  "Good Bye!"; }
    function _night(){  "Good Night!"; }
?>

<html>
    <head>!-- required files -- </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="thisDIV">
            <? echo _hello(); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            This is another Division.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible that I just want to reload the function _hello() in the division (id=thisDIV) by using javascript? Or ajax, Jquery ajax or whatever.. How can I make it? Thanks!

Comment: For that you have to send ajax request with some parameters and at server side you can have logic to call function according to parameter value.

Comment: to echo something first of all return something from the functions **function _hello(){ return "Hello world!"; }**

Answer (score 2):

You could add a querystring to your URL and then tie that to what function you want to run:

eg: http://myurl.com/page.php?function=hello

In page.php:

```
$function = $_GET['function'];

if($function == "hello") {
    hello();
}
```

etc etc

Comment: @PaulLing Is that you expecting or something else ?